# Why is there a 'bytes' parameter in UdpClient.Send?

Tags: .net, udpclient

There is an overload of [UdpClient.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82dxxas0.aspx) method that accepts dgram, bytes, and an endpoint.

```
public int Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes, IPEndPoint endPoint)
```

in MSDN documentation, the description for the 'bytes' parameter is as following.

> bytes 
>   Type : System.Int32 
>   The number of bytes in the datagram.

Why is there a 'bytes' parameter? Isn't it possible to figure out the number of bytes in the dgram array inside the Send method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you "Send" on the network you are typically sending a stream of bytes that you have encoded from some other source. Serialisation etc.

You use this overload so that you can provide a buffer and potentially send just a subsection of the bytes of that buffer.

Often you'll create a larger buffer, but you might only populate a section of it. This way you can just send that buffer and say Please only send X bytes from my buffer.